# How I can generate dynamic buttons in Jbuilder java

Tags: java, jbuilder

How can I generate dynamic buttons in Jbuilder Java, and change the number of buttons according to the length of a word? I want to have as many buttons as the number of characters in a word for a scrabble game application.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FR1Ak.png]